# Jlsit, determine the biggest item

Tags: java, jlist

So imagine that you in "c:/" have a folder called "Diretorio" And inside of that folder you have subfolders, and inside them you have more folders (C:/Diretorio/Antonio/Documentos/Temp[this is the path]), and in jlist i shearch and i made a code that when it start appear on Jlist:

> C:\Diretorio\Antonio
>
> C:\Diretorio\Antonio\Documentos
>
> C:\Diretorio\Antonio\Documentos\Temp

And my question is, is it possible to somehow just appear the " C:\Diretorio\Antonio\Documentos\Temp" on jlist items?

---------------Code-------------------

```
public teste_borrar2() throws IOException {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        File raiz = new File("C:\\Diretorio\\");


         listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        listModel = displayDirectoryContents(raiz);
}


public static DefaultListModel displayDirectoryContents(File dir) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()){

                System.out.println("Directory Name==>:" + file);

               displayDirectoryContents(file);
                listModel.addElement(file);

            }
            }
        return listModel;

    }
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "biggest one" compared to what? Path length? Directory size?

Comment: If you are looking for the longest string, you can use the length()-Method of String-class. But your question should be more specific and also show what you tried until now

Comment: @explv I think now it's better

Comment: @abarisone see if you understand now pls

Comment: @Tom i think now you will understand

Comment: @Supahupe see if you understand now my qustion pls

Comment: *"i think now you will understand"* No I don't since you still don't explain what the "biggest one" is. What is the criteria to be the biggest one?

Comment: Please edit your question for more details instead of using the answer section. But I still do not understand what you want. Are you looking for the longest path below "C:\Diretorio\Antonio"? Do you want to add the paths as items to a JList? Do you only want to add "C:\Diretorio\Antonio\Documentos\Temp" to the JList? Or just the items below this folder? And also please show your code or a simple example what is your idea

Comment: @Tom "the biggest one" is the biggest path.
When i start the program(Jlist), this 3 path's appear, and i just want to appear "the biggest one", that is "C:\Diretorio\Antonio\Documentos\Temp" appear on Jlist item

Comment: As you have the pathes as Strings, use the String.length()-Method then which will tell you the longest of the pathes. Figger this one out and add it to your JList

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your comment, you just want to find the longest of your pathes represented as Strings. You can do it like this:

```
String[] pathes = new String[3];
//add your pathes to array here
String longestString = "";
for(int i = 0; i < pathes.length; i++) {
   if (pathes[i].length() > longestString.length()) {
       longestString = pathes[i]
   }
}
//add longestPath to your JList
```